# Cant connect to MySQL Server in ASP.NET to make migrations

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, linux

i want to make migrations to a MySQL Database on my linux machine.
But everytime i want to apply the migrations i got following error:

> An error occurred using the connection to database '' on server '82.XXX.XXX.XXX'.

This is my connection string:

```
"IntranetConnection": "Server=82.XXX.XXX.XXX; Port=3306; Database=nvt; Uid=root; Pwd=PASSWORDX;"
```

I got this in my ConfigureServices

```
        var conntectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("IntranetConnection");

        services.AddDbContext<AuthenticationConext>(options =>
        options.UseMySql(conntectionString,
        new MySqlServerVersion(new Version(8, 0, 21)),
        mySqlOptions => mySqlOptions.CharSetBehavior(CharSetBehavior.NeverAppend)
        .EnableRetryOnFailure())
        .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
        .EnableDetailedErrors());
```

Im using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure for this.

I can connect to my database via MySQL Workbench but not with asp.net...

Did someone faced that issue in the past?

Comment: Is there any more detail to the error message?

Comment: @Léon-Zimmermann I had similar issue with MySQL. Here's my connection string: `server=localhost:3306;user=xxxxxxxxxxxxx;password=xxxxxxxxxx;database=DB1;TreatTinyAsBoolean=true;` What version of Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql do you use?